# Getting another URL's Javascript variable in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I was wondering if there was some way to get a javascript variable from another url into a variable within PHP?

For example:

A page called exampleurl.com/page (which I do not have control over) with some inline javascript like:

```
function examplefunction() {
    evar = "http://ikmp.co/Usdfio1";
}
```

Assuming there's HTML and other javascript surrounding this variable I want, how would I be able to retrieve it? Is there a special function to do this, or would it be easier to simply parse the HTML through PHP and then trim the variable to what I want?

In theory, the PHP would have a URL set to retrieve the JS from, and it would echo only what is in that variable.

PHP code (hypothetical) at mysite.com/getvariable.php:

```
$url = 'exampleurl.com/page';
$js_var =  get_js_data($url, $evar);
echo $js_var;
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out here!

Comment: @Mrdoctor Kovacic: in other words, you'd like to parse text contents of a page to extract anything resembling javascript?  Specifically anything in between say "function examplefunction() {" text and a matching closing curly bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

**HTML FILE:**

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script> 
    var javascriptVar ='pie'; //this is whatever the js variable you want it to be

    $('#result').load('path/to/my/myphpfile.php?var='+javascriptVar );
    </script>
```

**myphpfile.php**

```
<?php
$javascriptVar =$_GET['var'];

echo $javascriptVar;
?>
```

*notice the php code HAS to be in a seperate file than the html for this to work*

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control over the JavaScript file, it's from another website.

Comment: you dont have to alter the external script. my js code can be on a different file on your server that simply retrieves the variable from the other website